# Product collection Sort by Custom attribute with yes/no Option

Tags: magento-1.8, collection, sorting

Hi I have created one attribute called `archive` whose type is Yes/No. So archive attribute for every product has either Yes/No.

Now I want to sort product collection so that all products whose archive value=YES should come at the end.

I tried:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
             ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()) 
             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
             ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable')
             ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
             ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
                 array('finset' => '37'))
               )
             ->addAttributeToSort('archive', 'desc');
```

But it does not work.

Printing `$collection->getSelect()` results in:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`,    
`price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS  
NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) 
AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`,  
`price_index`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN  
`catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND 
cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.category_id = '37' INNER JOIN 
`catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id 
AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 WHERE 
(`e`.`type_id` = 'configurable')
```

Comment: how's it getting sorted now?

Comment: Try to print your SQL query and check. `print $collection->getSelect();`

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the `archive` attribute is added to the flat product data by setting `Used in Product Listing` to yes. Also it's probably better to load the product collection via the `catalog/category` model instead of joining another table.

Also, to have **yes** come as last make the order *ascending* instead of *descending*

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(37);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection()
   ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
   ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable')
   ->addAttributeToSort('archive', 'asc');
```

Comment: where I do this modify?

Comment: @ClaudioPomo can you be more specific? You mean where you set the attribute flat data property?

Comment: Where is the file to update? Or in which part of magento core I have to edit?

Comment: @ClaudioPomo This was actually an answer to some script OP wrote. Why not post your exact question with case and I promise to take a look :)

Comment: [This is](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120014/sort-product-by-custom-attribute) my question